# What is the reason for performance difference?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a report, for that I have written 2 different type of query. But I am seeing a huge performance difference between these 2 methods. What may be the reason? My main table (suppose table A) contain a date column. I am filtering the data based on date. Around 10 table join I have to do with this table.

First method:

```
select A.id,A1.name,...
from table A
join A1
join A2 ....A10
where A.Cdate >= @date
and A.Cdate <= @date
```

Second method:

```
With CTE as(select A.id from A where A.Cdate>=@date and A.Cdate<=@date)
select CTE.id, A1.name,.... from CTE join A1 join A2....A10
```

Here second method is fast. What is the reason? In first method, the filtered data of A only will be join with other tables data right?

Comment: just out of curiosity are both queries bring back the exact same data?

Answer (score 1):

Execution plans will tell us for sure, but likely if the CTE is able to filter out a lot of rows before the join, a more optimal join approach may have been chosen (for example merge instead of hash). SQL isn't *supposed* to work that way - in theory those two should execute the same way. But in practice we find that SQL Server's optimizer isn't perfect and can be swayed in different ways based on a variety of factors, including statistics, selectivity, parallelism, a pre-existing version of that plan in the cache, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion.You should be able to answer this question yourself as you have both the plans. Did you compare the two plans? Are those similar? Also, when performance is bad what do you mean ,is it time or cpu time or IO's or what did you compare?

Thus before you post any question  you should check these counters and I am sure they will provide with some kind of answers in most of cases.

CTE is for managing the code it wont improve the performance of query automatically. CTE's will be expanded by optimizer and thus in your case these both should have same queries after transformation or expansion and thus similar plans.

Comment: *Should*, yes, but don't. Otherwise there wouldn't be a question here.

Comment: No I have seen people just say two queries are similar but one is performing bad.I think unless other people on post know the query and ddl etc they cant say anything about the perf. Thus I expect the people to have a first look themselves(this will help them to learn) and then if theyask question they should include all of these if possible to provide a specific answer rather than a generic or it depends answer.

Comment: Actualy i dont have permission to see the execution plan due to some reason.

Comment: @NikRED you are responsible for tuning queries and you can't view execution plans? Then your boss (or whoever controls your permissions) is doing it wrong.

Comment: Also, withpout looking at plan everything will be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

CTE is basically for the handling the more complex code(be it recursive or having subquery), but you need to check the execution plan regarding the improvement of the 2 different queries. 
You can check for the use of CTE at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Just a note, in many scenarios, temp tables gives better performance then CTE also, so you should give a try to temp tables as well.
Reference : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/d040d19d-016e-4a21-bf44-a0359fb3c7fb

Comment: Can you please tell me how is it wrong, although just below I have written that temp tables yields better result then CTE. Can you please tell where I missed out?

Comment: Your first sentence seems to guarantee that CTEs are always faster than joins. I'm not going to provide counter-examples in a comment, but I wouldn't make that promise, since I know for a fact that it's not always true. (Also not sure why you've mentioned "recursive" in this scenario - doesn't seem relevant.)

Comment: What I meant in my post was that cte is better then joins in a recursive scenario, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Again, that is not universally true, and I have no idea why we're talking about recursion. What recursive query exists in the question?

Comment: Yes Aaron, there was no recurssion in this query, and I made a generalized statement. So I was curious just for my knowledge and development, that how come join be faster then cte in a recursive scenario?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. My point is that there is no definitive answer like "join is always faster than CTE" or "recursive CTE is always faster than join" or "merge join is always faster than hash join." There are more variables involved that make it impossible for your first sentence to have any credibility whatsoever. For that sentence, I think you're answering a question about gas mileage in cars by mentioning how light your bike is.

Comment: If you're going to say "it is a well known fact" you should provide a link to a reference that states such. I don't believe such a reference exists.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14219/discussion-between-user1501472-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: Also please be aware that "the result of a CTE" is not always reused; in many cases if you reference a CTE twice in the subsequent query, the query will be evaluated twice. A lot of people think CTEs are primarily used to improve performance, but like views, they are usually used for convenience.